# remove checked attribute from htmlgenericcontrol

Tags: jquery, .net, asp.net

I'm using jquery plugin which need list items to be like:

```
<input name="star3" type="radio" class="star" checked="checked"/>
```

I added runat="server" to that. Is there a way to remove on codebehind checked attribute (not change it, just remove it). It is now htmlGenericControl as I suppose.

thanks for help

Comment: Can I ask, why you want to remove Cheecked attribute?

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
$("input:radio[name='star3']").attr("checked", false);
```

OR

```
$("input:radio[name='star3']").remoevAttr("checked");
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do

```
htmlGenericControl1.Attributes.Remove("checked")
```

or if the server control has an id like this

```
<input name="star3" type="radio" class="star" checked="checked" 
                                runat="server" id="radio1"/>
```

you can do

```
radio1.Attributes.Remove("checked");
```